# Who is responsible to load files in /etc/ld.so.preload?

Tags: assembly, nasm, ld, glibc, dynamic-linking

I have earlier thought, the programs which are linked to dynamic libraries looks into `/etc/ld.so.preload`.

But, somewhere I have read that

> All programs try to open /etc/ld.so.preload, this behavior is baked into Glibc.

Hence, to avoid glibc I thought of writing the program in assembly code. Compiled it using `nasm` and `ld`. Still it is loading `/etc/ld.so.preload` libraries.

My ultimate goal is to write a program which do not tries to load libraries in `/etc/ld.so.preload`.
For that I need to know who is responsible to load this and how can I write such a program(no language constraint)?

PS : My real problem is that I want to edit `/etc/ld.so.preload` to include my library. But In case if this library happens to be a broken one then every single command on my machine breaks and I cannot do anything on the machine. Hence, for such a case I want to keep a utility handy which would delete my library from `/etc/ld.so.preload`. In that case this utility as well as `sudo` must be completely statically linked.

Comment: I'm more interested in your *actual* problem, the problem you try to solve by not using the standard C library. Why don't you want to use the platforms standard C library?

Comment: If you compile with static linking I don't think it needs `ld.so.preload`.

Comment: @Barmar you are right. The program is not loading those libraries, just found out that actually I am running it using sudo, and sudo needs ld.so.preload. Can we by any means make sudo statically linked?

Comment: This is a re-ask of (deleted) [Compiling assembly program which will not use glibc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59266455/compiling-assembly-program-which-will-not-use-glibc), in case this looks familiar to anyone else.

Comment: *sudo needs ld.so.preload* Really needs?  Or do you just mean tries to load?  `sudo` works on my Arch Linux system which doesn't have an `/etc/ld.so.preload`

Comment: "My ultimate goal is to" -- that goal makes no sense. What are you *really* trying to achieve? See also http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @PeterCordes Sorry I meant it tries to load.

Comment: @EmployedRussian I have edited the post to include my real problem

Comment: *In that case this utility as well as sudo must be completely statically linked.*

Not if your utility itself is setuid-root as well as statically linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Who is responsible to load files in /etc/ld.so.preload?

The dynamic linker is. When using GLIBC, the dynamic linker is `ld-linux.so`.

> Compiled it using nasm and ld. Still it is loading /etc/ld.so.preload libraries.

Either you linked against GLIBC dynamically, or the statement above is false.

> actually I am running it using sudo, and sudo needs ld.so.preload. Can we by any means make sudo statically linked?

You can rebuild many programs to be statically linked, yes. But this has costs (disk space, must rebuild all programs for every security fix, etc.), and may not be entirely trivial. It's also unlikely to fix any real problem you have.

> My real problem is that I want to edit /etc/ld.so.preload to include my library. But In case if this library happens to be a broken one then every single command on my machine breaks and I cannot do anything on the machine. Hence, for such a case I want to keep a utility handy which would delete my library from /etc/ld.so.preload. In that case this utility as well as sudo must be completely statically linked.

The solution to this problem is to do what Russ Ridge suggested in a comment on this answer: "install a statically linked version of [BusyBox](https://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html)".

BusyBox has both `su` and `rm` commands that you desire.

An alternative solution is to learn how to use [Linux recovery CD](http://www.system-rescue-cd.org/) -- this may come in handy in a lot of situations, so learning how to recover a system is well worth the effort.

Comment: Having a statically linked set of command line tools available can come in handy when you've edited `ld.so.preload` so that `ld-linux.so` always loads a broken dynamical library of your own creation. I suggested that the original poster install a statically linked version of BusyBox in a comment to a now deleted question, but apparently the original poster doesn't understand how this would be helpful.

Comment: You are right, I want to edit ```/etc/ld.so.preload```, it had happened that my library was broken and hence every single command was breaking and my machine was on toss. Hence, if this happens, I want to keep a (statically linked) utiltiy handy which would work and delete that entry form the ld.so.preload

Comment: @EmployedRussian statically linked busybox was giving me an error while using su : ' must be suid to work properly',I think the sbit must be set for the busybox binary. Instead, I made my utility as statically linked and set its sbit. Its working now. Thanks for the answer/lead.

Comment: @aaa: then your BusyBox install is arguably broken, and not useful for recovery purposes.  I assume BusyBox is still supposed to be able to parse `/etc/shadow` and verify that you know the root password, but if your system doesn't have a root password then it wouldn't be useful.  Maybe your distro's busybox packaging has some docs about why they decided not to make it suid by default, and how to make it useful if you want that functionality.  But yes, making your own tool SUID root is sufficient to recover from this one specific possible problem, and a USB boot stick can do everything else.